# How do I set what beta branch I want to upload my build to in Steamworks?

Tags: steam, steamworks

I have many beta branches, and when uploading the game I just run a command which executes the `app-build-xxxx.vdf` file. How do I set what specific branch I want those changes to be uploaded to? My configuration file looks something like this:

```
"appid"           "xxxxx"
"desc"            "Beta branch xxxx "     

"buildoutput"     "..\output\"                         
"contentroot"     "..\..\Game\"             

"setlive"         "<Name of the branch here as it is in steamworks>"
```

Comment: What do the docs say? Have you tried the `setlive` field?

Comment: well I am a bit scared to make that build public to everyone to be honest hehe. That is what I understood from the docu but I could not find much information about it on the documentation

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/sdk/uploading) for the `setlive` parameters say:

> Branch name to automatically set live after successful build, none if empty.
> Note that the 'default' branch can not be set live automatically. That must be done through the App Admin panel.

You cannot accidentally set the default branch live, if that's what you are worrying about. If you are worried about accidentally setting another beta-branch live while testing, just create another password protected branch for testing this before deploying it into your proper build pipeline.

Comment: yeah my worry is (probably a silly question but being new and english not being my first language) if setlive is not making it public to everybody right? just the people from my team who has the beta code. am I right? Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: The docs do not mention any change it would do in the branch. It just sets it live on the branch, regardless of and without changing the settings (like the password) of the branch. If you are ultra worried, why not check out the revision of your latest public release, make a meaningless change (like edit a text or whatever), and try with that?